# Does std::unordered_map equality depend on insertion order

Tags: c++, unordered-map

If you create two `std::unordered_map` containers using the same set of (non equal) key-value pairs, but inserted in a different order (so the containers hold equal elements, but potentially in different orders), are the containers guaranteed to be equal, according to the equality operator ([`operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_cmp)). I'm assuming that the hash-code and equality operators of the container elements satisfy all the required constraints on their implementation.

Comment: Have you tried it? Also, that guarantee would follow from the according ISO standard, so that indirectly contain the answer.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've tried, and the answer seems to be "yes, it depends on insertion order", but I'm not sure whether that is because I've made a mistake.

Comment: No. (This space intentionally left blank)

Comment: Sample [code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SwJVvqEXsErPYhHn) showing equality of all permutations of insertion sequences for a map of 4 pairs<char, string>

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt "Have you tried it" can't tell you whether "it doesn't depend on insertion order" is a feature of this implementation, or is guaranteed for all C++ implementations.  (I suppose it *can* tell you that "it does depend on insertion order" - but all the answers below show that that would be a bug in the implementation.)

Comment: Note that `operator==` does not take into account non-salient attributes of the container. So just because they do compare equal does not guarantee that they will behave identical in all possible contexts. For example, the exact runtime cost for lookup of a specific element could still be different on the two containers.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, they're guaranteed to return equal in this case. The specific wording (from N4659, §[unord.req]/12) is:

> Two unordered containers `a` and `b` compare equal if `a.size() == b.size()` and, for every equivalent-key group `[Ea1, Ea2)` obtained from `a.equal_range(Ea1)`, there exists an equivalent-key group `[Eb1, Eb2)` obtained from `b.equal_range(Ea1)`, such that `is_permutation(Ea1, Ea2, Eb1, Eb2)` returns `true`.

So, as long as the keys (and associated values) in one are the same as the other (but possibly in a differently-permuted order), it will compare equal.

Comment: Nice. Any idea how it is implemented? I can see a pure hash table implementing this is in O(n log n), (i.e. collect the keys, sort them by their hash, check the values) but maybe there's better

Comment: @Ant Normally it is implemented as a balanced binary search tree, like red-black tree.

Comment: @hgminh I meant, how is the equality comparison algorithm implemented (granted, it most likely depends on the underlying structure)

Comment: @hgm -- Red black tree? This question concerns unordered maps, not (ordered) maps.

Comment: @Ant: Unordered containers are hash tables, so they start out with all they keys that hashed to the same value in the same bucket. I'd expect they'd actually use `std::is_permutation` to check for keys in the same bucket. [That can be O(n)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86241/is-permutation-on-sequence-containers-in-on-complexity-follow-up).

Comment: @Ant - The quote from the standard pertains to all unordered containers. This simplifies greatly if there is at most one entry per key, as is the case with an unordered_map. Walking over the key-value pairs in the first map is O(N). Finding the equivalent key-value pair in the second map is O(1) on average, O(N) worst case. So `operator==` for an unordered map is O(N) on average, O(N^2) worst case.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - Neither the gcc nor llvm implementations of `operator==` for two unordered maps use `std::is_permutation`. That's extreme overkill for an unordered map. Both walk over the key value pairs in the first argument and use `find` instead of `equal_range` to obtain the equivalent key-value pair (if it exists) in the second argument.

Comment: @DavidHammen: I guess I shouldn't be surprised. You usually try to keep buckets really small anyway, so there's rarely much point in optimizing computational complexity of operations inside a bucket.

Comment: So... Equavalence is tested on keys only, not on stored values? Or am I misunderstanding the wording?

Comment: @André: Sorry, I should probably fix the wording--but it also requires that the keys have the same associated values.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks, that makes sense, but it is not easy to grasp from the answer (or the wording of the standard).

Answer (score 14):

From [[unord.red]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unord.req#12)

> Two unordered containers `a` and `b` compare equal if `a.size() == b.size()` and, for every equivalent-key group `[Ea1, Ea2)` obtained from `a.equal_­range(Ea1)`, there exists an equivalent-key group `[Eb1, Eb2)` obtained from `b.equal_­range(Ea1)`, such that `is_­permutation(Ea1, Ea2, Eb1, Eb2)` returns `true`. [...]

So, as long as the keys are the same and the size is the same the containers will compare equal no matter what order the keys are in.

Answer (score 3):

Below are quotes from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_cmp) about the std:unordered_map, operator==,!=(std::unordered_map):

> The contents of two unordered containers lhs and rhs are equal if the following conditions hold:
>
> - lhs.size() == rhs.size()
> - each group of equivalent elements [lhs_eq1, lhs_eq2) obtained from lhs.equal_range(lhs_eq1) has a corresponding group of equivalent elements in the other container [rhs_eq1, rhs_eq2) obtained from rhs.equal_range(rhs_eq1), that has the following properties:
>
>   - std::distance(lhs_eq1, lhs_eq2) == std::distance(rhs_eq1, rhs_eq2).
>   - std::is_permutation(lhs_eq1, lhs_eq2, rhs_eq1) == true.

Note that:

> The behavior is undefined if Key or T are not EqualityComparable.
>
> The behavior is also undefined if Hash and KeyEqual do (until C++20)KeyEqual does (since C++20) not have the same behavior on lhs and rhs or if operator== for Key is not a refinement of the partition into equivalent-key groups introduced by KeyEqual (that is, if two elements that compare equal using operator== fall into different partitions)

Finally, to consider is the complexity:

> Proportional to N calls to operator== on value_type, calls to the predicate returned by key_eq, and calls to the hasher returned by hash_function, in the average case, proportional to N2 in the worst case where N is the size of the container.

Therefore, if both unordered maps have the same size, and each key in one of the containers is looked for in the other plus, if it happens to be  found then their values are compared then they are the considered the same.